# Loading TPCH in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

i am having trouble importing the data of the TPCH-Benchmark into my monetDB-Database.

I am creating the first table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "tpch"."customer" ( "c_custkey"    INTEGER       NOT NULL,  "c_name"       VARCHAR(25)   NOT NULL,"c_address"    VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,"c_nationkey"  INTEGER       NOT NULL,"c_phone"      VARCHAR(15)   NOT NULL,"c_acctbal"    DOUBLE        NOT NULL,"c_mktsegment" VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,"c_comment"    VARCHAR(117)  NOT NULL);
```

and then when i try to insert data into it with the following:

```
COPY INTO tpch.customer FROM 'PATH/tpcdskew/customer.tbl' using delimiters '|','\n';
```

i get the following error:

> 'ailed to import table Leftover data '

the "f" that seems to be missing at the start is actually missing for me and the ' are there in the output too.

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you generate the TPCH data?
Probably you have to remove the last "|" at end of each line.

I use "sed 's/.$//' oldfile.tbl > newfile.tbl" to do that.

Afterwards you should be able to fill your tables.